# IntelliJ can't find Scanner class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij IDEA.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner scanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

        int a = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(a);
}
```

The problem is that when I run it, it works. But, Intellij cannot find Scanner class. It is underlining with red color.

How to fix this?

Comment: Hovering over the red-line, I get Cannot resolve symbol. And it is not only for Scanner class. System.out.println cannot be found too.  The strage part is that it is compiling and running fine

Comment: If you can successfully compile it and run it then it may be some false-positive code analysis error ... IntelliJ gives me those from time to time (possibly a bug in the IDE?). When I restart IntelliJ it usually disappears. This also happens when you don't have project SDK defined, but since you can compile and run it that's probably not the case.

Comment: I restarted the IDE, not helping. I also think that it is a bug in IDE or something

Comment: Try to clear IntelliJ cache: `File | Invalidate Caches / Restart..`

Answer (score 3):

First you should import the Scanner like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;// in the top!
```

and then try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int a = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.println(a);
}
```

Comment: even in the import I get this error. But it is compiling well

Answer (score -1):

Right click on code editor window and click on run.

Comment: Do you think that will remove the "underlining with red color."?