# Cannot resolve Symbol "Scanner" Java

Tags: java, intellij-idea

```java
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("hello world !");
    }
}
```

It says that `Scanner` cannot resolve symbol

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell without more info. Assuming you're using at least Java 5 the IDE should pick up the class so maybe you've misconfigured your project or it's a hickup in the IDE (I know this more from Eclipse than from IntelliJ though).

Comment: Have you configured your JDK? Because `println` is also marked red.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [IntelliJ can't find Scanner class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703091/intellij-cant-find-scanner-class), but it doesn't really have a good answer. You can try Anton Dozortsev's suggestion and [Invalidate IntelliJ's caches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703091/intellij-cant-find-scanner-class#comment42001040_26703091).